# How do i mask the bits i dont want from my machinecode?

Tags: c, bit-shift, bitmask, machine-code

So I have a txt file that I'm taking numbers in like 02324020 which is the machine code from the MIPS instruction: `add $t0, $s1, $s2`

When it's in binary and cut into sections of 6,5,5,5,5,6 the numbers taken are: 0,17,18,8,0,20

This gives the idea of the instruction as R[rd] = R[rs]+R[rt] and the number from 26-31 is opcode 0 meaning R format, rd=8, rs=17, rt=18

I'm trying to mask the bits so I only see the bits between 21-25 and then receive the number that they are: 0,17,18,8,0,20 because shifting to the right: `printf("\n%x\n", code >>26);` gives me the opcode 0 and tells me its the R format.

So now I'm trying to find the 17 but I don't know what to place after `& 0b` in:

```
printf("\n%x\n", code >>21 & 0b____);
```

I could really use an example to find the remaining numbers from my number 02324020

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    unsigned int code = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
    int result = fscanf(fp, "%x", &code);
    printf("\n hex-1: %08X, decimal-1: %d \n", code, code);

    printf("\n%x\n", code >>26);
    printf("\n%x\n", code >>21 & 0x0b00000011111); //what can i do to change this
    while (result != EOF)
    {
        result = fscanf(fp, "%x", &code);
        printf("\n read hex: %08X, decimal: %d \n", code, code);
        if(feof(fp))
        {
            puts("EOF");
            break;
        }//if
    }//while
}
```

Comment: Doing `code >> 21 & 0b11111` should give you the 17 you're looking for. Is that not working?

Comment: !!! that does work, but why ob11111? and how would it change when i try to get the 18 next?

Comment: Edit: wait i tried it with the other sections and they work oh my god that was so simple i cant believe it, thank you!

Comment: Aha there you go!

Comment: just one last thing i also need to find I formats and with finding the immediate would it be something like printf("\n%x\n", y & 0b1111111111111111); so for example 0x8e67fffb would give -5 for its immediate

Comment: Yep, that'll give you the immediate value.

Comment: As an aside (I thought I saw your comment on fffb != -5): 0xfffb is how you would represent the number -5. To display it properly, you can cast it like this: `(short)0xfffb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a binary number, you'd use `0b___` (as you've mentioned in your answer), not `0x0b0___`.

To extract the number you need, you'd have to bit-shift `code` so that the bits you're interested in are at the right-most end. Then `OR` only those bits you're interested in. Putting this together, you have:

```
printf("\n%x\n", code >> 26);
printf("\n%x\n", code >> 21 &  0b11111);
printf("\n%x\n", code >> 16 &  0b11111);
printf("\n%x\n", code >> 11 &  0b11111);
printf("\n%x\n", code >>  6 &  0b11111);
printf("\n%x\n", code       & 0b111111);
```